# Performance/Time issue in different machines due to threading in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I am using Threading in my Java project. When I am running my project on my Machine than it takes more time (approx 30min) in comparison to other Machine. Both Machines have same 64bit configuration and use 32bit JDK 1.5.16.
So is it because of Java Threading?
any ideas?? please suggest

Thanks!

****Added Information****

```
First Machine: OS - WIN 7 (64 bit), RAM - 8 GB
Second Machine: OS - WIN 8 (64 bit) , RAM - 16 GB
```

Even the configuration of 2nd machine is higher than the first machine, then It takes 30 to 50 mins more as compared to first one.

Comment: What are the characteristics of both: RAM, HDD, SSD, Processor(s), other SW running,etc,  etc ?

Comment: do both machines have the Java memory options?

Comment: Add the requested details so that your question gets reopened. We have no crystal balls.

Comment: Information updated, Please see that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be a be a million reasons. But most importantly, before you start to analyze the cause, make sure your benchmark isn't broken. Because in a lot of cases that is the cause and hunting phantom performance issue is a huge waste of time and often leads to wrong conclusions.

For example, make sure you let your benchmark run long enough (e.g. 5 or 10 minutes) so that things like jit compilation is not that influential.

Also make sure that both machines run exactly the same benchmark under the same environmental settings/behahvior.

Once you verified that the benchmark is fine, you could have a look with a profiler (e.g. jprofiler or jvisualvm if you don't have a decent profiler).

Answer (score 7):

following reasons could be possible,

1.both machines though have same configuration but at a point of time both of them having same number of processes running (daemons,services,apps etc) if that is not the case then please make that equal as performance test should be carried out on exactly same environment for comparisons (then only your test is valid)

2.both machines have exactly hardware configuration (processor,memory etc)

3.though both machines have java version same but scheduling service differs from OS to OS which can be a cause.

4.in some OSes there are some special features available for concurrent programs, performance, threading which again can cause performance.

please consider all these things while drawing any conclusion.

run your test multiple times and take average for confirmation which is valid measure than single run.